# Safely remove needed before rebooting or shutting down computer?

Tags: shutdown, unmounting, removable-storage

Is it necessary to use the safely remove function to safely remove your usb stick or external hard drive before rebooting, shutting down computer, using standby or hibernation mode? (or is this done automatically?)

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 Beta.

Comment: Devices should be safely unmounted during a lawful shutdown or reboot. Standby or hibernation will probably be fine, so long as you don't yank the drive while it's standby'd or hibernated.

Answer (score 3):

The shutdown process somewhere includes `umount -a` that's effectively the same as "safely remove"  Once the shutdown is finished it's safe.